# How would I add two num_rows together?

Tags: php

I'm having a little bit of trouble with my PHP code.

I'd like to add two num_rows together so that it shows in the top navigation bar.

My code is as follows:

```
$get_unread_query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT opened FROM pvt_messages WHERE user_to='$user' && opened='no'");
$get_unread_rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_unread_query);
$unread_numrows = mysqli_num_rows($get_unread_query);
$unread_numrows = "(".$unread_numrows.")";

$friendRequests = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM friend_requests WHERE user_to='$user'");
$friend_numrows = mysqli_num_rows($friendRequests);
$friend_numrows = "(".$friend_numrows.")";

$notifications = $unread_numrows + $friend_numrows;
$notifications = "(".$notifications.")";
```

As you can see `$notifications = $unread_numrows + $friend_numrows`.

This should add the $unread_numrows to the $friend_numrows and show the result.

So for example, if $unread_numrows holds 1 and $friend_numrows holds 1 as well, the result would show 2 in the top navigation bar.

As most of you know, this code does not work. So how would I make it work?

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: "As most of you know, this code does not work." ...no, actually I don't. What is your current output? After having enabled all errors and warnings, what does PHP tell you?

Comment: The code you have posted doesn't actually display anything anywhere. It's far from clear what you're asking.

Comment: Why are you adding parentheses around integers you try to add?

Comment: There are no errors or warnings shown. I don't think that the syntax itself is correct though..

Comment: I'm displaying the end result, which in my case would be $notifications

Comment: @Sumurai8 I've done that so it looks like (1) or (2) in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you wrap your numrows with a string "()"..
You can do it after you calculate the total sum like this:

```
$get_unread_query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT opened FROM pvt_messages WHERE user_to='$user' && opened='no'");
$get_unread_rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_unread_query);
$unread_numrows = mysqli_num_rows($get_unread_query); // number

$friendRequests = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM friend_requests WHERE user_to='$user'");
$friend_numrows = mysqli_num_rows($friendRequests); // number

$notifications = $unread_numrows + $friend_numrows; // number

// now you can turn them all to strings
$notifications = "(".$notifications.")";
$unread_numrows = "(".$unread_numrows.")";
$friend_numrows = "(".$friend_numrows.")";
```

Answer (score 0):

$notifications is because of the line:

```
$notifications = $unread_numrows + $friend_numrows;
```

declared as int double, but not as a String.

In the next line your treating it as a string maybe try this:

```
$sum = $unread_numrows + $friend_numrows;
$notifications = "(" + $sum + ")"
```